# Launch component into container defined by included launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

This question can be regarded as an extension of the question https://answers.ros.org/question/378140/launch-component-into-existing-container/ and https://answers.ros.org/question/306935/ros2-include-a-launch-file-from-a-launch-file/.

**Situation:** I have a "base" launch file which describes a collection of nodes. Some of these nodes are launched in a component container. The base launch file is already fairly complex. I do not want to add to it any further.

**Goal:** To further expand the project, I want to build upon the base rather than to change it. I want to create a launch file which includes the base launch file and then describes some more nodes to launch. *Some of these nodes need to be added to the component container which is described by the included launch file.*

This is what I have so far (includes omitted for readability):

```
base_package_directory = get_package_share_directory('base_package')
base_launch_description = IncludeLaunchDescription(PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(base_package + '/launch/base.py'))
base_container = next(e for e in base_vehicle.get_sub_entities()[0].entities if isinstance(e, ComposableNodeContainer))
additional_node = LoadComposableNodes(
    composable_node_descriptions = [ComposableNode(
        name = 'additional_node',
        package = 'additional_package',
        plugin = 'additional_node',
    )],
    target_container = base_container,
)
return launch.LaunchDescription([base_launch_description, additional_node])
```

This looks terribly ugly. Also, it results in an error:

```
RuntimeError: cannot access 'node_name' before executing action
```

Where `node_name` is an attribute of the `ComposableNodeContainer` "base_container".

My guts are telling me "you are doing it wrong" – especially when looking at line 2 and 3. How do I do this right?

Kind regards
Hermann

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388183/launch-component-into-container-defined-by-included-launch-file/) by [fhwedel-hoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/72004/fhwedel-hoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you know the container name, then you can use that name as the `target_container`:

```
...
additional_node = LoadComposableNodes(
    composable_node_descriptions=[ComposableNode(
        name='additional_node',
        package='additional_package',
        plugin='additional_node')],
   target_container='base_container_node_name')
```

...

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2021-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fhwedel-hoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/72004/fhwedel-hoe/) on 2021-10-11**:
Thank you. :) Small hint for the next one looking at this: It needs to be the "fully qualified" name. In my case, a namespace is involved. The target_container becomes '/whatever_namespace/base_container_node_name'.